# How to Load JSON Array First Object at TableViewFirst Section and Remaining object at Second Section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

i am newbie in iOS development. I make an application that Contain JSON Data i want to show JSON array first Object in to TableView First Section and all remaining object of data are shown in to TableView Second Section and My Tableview Each Section Contain Different TableViewCell i code for that then it load Different Cell as i want but data are not loaded in to each cell

Here I code For First Section is

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifierOne=@"CellOne";
    CustumCell *cellOne =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierOne];
    if (cellOne == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibOne=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cellOne=[nibOne objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    {
        [cellOne.spinner startAnimating];
        NSDictionary *dict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"front_image"];
        [cellOne.storeImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[img2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Setting.png"] options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
         {
             [cellOne.spinner stopAnimating];
             cellOne.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

         }];
        NSString *title=[dict valueForKey:@"title"];
        cellOne.titleLabel.text=title;

        NSString *shrtDescrpt=[dict valueForKey:@"short_description"];
        cellOne.shortDescriptionLabel.text=shrtDescrpt;
    }
    return cellOne;
}
}
```

And when i run Application that it contain error in line

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Please Give me Solution and which code i write for Second Section to load array remaining object.

and Tableview Row and Section Code is

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
{ 
return 2;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return self.imageArray.count - 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Print the log self.imageArray

Comment: Not run it Contain Error in  NSDictionary *dict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:1]; this line.

Comment: Ashish remove the 1 value in the array and print it

Comment: But bro i want in my first Section data value at object one means first arry value and section two i want remainning value please give me solution.

Comment: Ok once print the log data for self.imageArray

Comment: it print all data value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64153/discussion-between-ramesh-muthe-and-ashish-gabani).